# FirebaseArray changing $id?

Tags: angularjs, firebase, angularfire

I am having issues with firebase. When I initially get the array of data from firebase the `$id` seems to give me the index value not the actual firebase generated id `-KB0ycB59XFrFrvn8SEB`.

This causes problems when I save or modify the data, because the data `$id` I am working with is `0` and not `-KB0ycB59XFrFrvn8SEB`.

```
// firebase ref
var ref = new Firebase(FBURL+'/events'),
    FbArray = $firebaseArray(ref);

// load events data array from firebase
FbArray.$loaded(function() {
    console.log(FbArray)
    $scope.events = FbArray;
});

$scope.eventSave = function(event) {
    // save an existing event to firbase
    FbArray.$save(event).then(function(ref) {
        console.log(ref.key());
    });
};
```

Comment: That sounds weird. Can you put a repro in a jsfiddle/jsbin?

Comment: Also: please don't use `$loaded()` in this way, it's pretty badly broken and not needed. As the [quickstart](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/libraries/angular/quickstart.html) shows `$scope.events = $firebaseArray(ref);` is all that's needed to bind an array to the scope.

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. You're looking how to save an item if you only have the index. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35534080/remove-just-a-item-by-angularfire/35536122#35536122 or any of the questions linked from there.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen
It is weird but here is how i fixed it, I changed
`$firebase.$loaded().then(function(data) {
          $scope.events = $firebase;
        });`
to
`var self=this;
$firebase.$loaded().then(function(data) {
            self.events = $firebase;
        });`
So, when i assign the data returned from firebase to $scope, the value of $id is changing from firebase generated id(-KB0ycB59XFrFrvn8SEB) to 0,1,2.. in that order.
When assigned to "self", the id stays the same.